# Find most common sum(s) in a list of integers

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to find the most common sum in a list of integers.

For instance, given the list `2,4,6,8`, the most common sums are 10, 12, and 14, as they can all be made in 2 ways:

`2 + 8 = 4 + 6 = 10
 2 + 4 + 6 = 4 + 8 = 12
 2 + 4 + 8 = 6 + 8 = 14`

Of course, the other possible sums only occur once. I know that a simple list like this can be brute-forced, but I would like some sort of general hint as to how I can solve this for larger lists. For instance, perhaps I can somehow utilize dynamic programming?

Comment: Given a list of `N` distinct integers, you may have `2^N` distinct sums. It looks suspiciously similar to the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).

Comment: Technically you will have to check for every subset to find out the most occurring sums. This can't be done any better. DP is usually used for maximizing or minimizing the goal to be met. For most occurring sums, I don't find any sub-problem we could create for this.

Comment: If this problem is from an online judge/programming competition, can you please provide a link to the original problem statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a variation of the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem). It can be done in psuedo polynomial time where time complexity is **O(n * sum)** using dynamic programming.

#### Recurrence relation

> dp(sum, i) = summation of dp(sum - a[i], i-1)

#### Explanation

Imagine that you have a solution for the number of ways any sum is possible with the subset of all elements from `0` to `i-1`. We denote it by `dp(sum, i - 1)` for all values of `sum`. In order to include a new element, `a[i]` in a valid subset that makes up `sum`, there has to be atleast one solution for `sum - a[i]` in the subset of elements from `0` to `i - 1`. Then, the number of ways to obtain a `sum` with subset of elements from `0` to `i` becomes the sum of number of ways to obtain `sum - a[i]` with a subset of elements `0` to `i - 1`.

#### Implementation

A bottom up implementation in C++ is as follows:

```
int mostCommonSum(const vector<int>& a) {
  int sum = 0;
  for(auto num: a) {
    sum += num;
  }
  vector<int> dp(sum + 1);
  dp[0] = 1;
  sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < (int)a.size(); i++) {
    sum += a[i];
    for(int j = sum; j >= 0; j--) {
      if (j - a[i] >= 0) {
        dp[j] += dp[j - a[i]];
      }
    }
  }
  int maxFrequency = -1;
  int mostFrequentSum = -1;
  for (int i = 0; i <= sum; i++) {
    if (dp[i] >= maxFrequency) {
      maxFrequency = dp[i];
      mostFrequentSum = i;
    }
  }
  return mostFrequentSum;
}
```

The implementation uses the same dynamic programming solution. However, it reduces the space complexity by only retaining the solution for `dp(sum, i - 1)` (and not dp(sum, i - 2), dp(sum, i - 3) and so on) as `dp[sum]`.

[Demo](https://ideone.com/7iZrEH)

Note: In your examples, most common sums are 6, 8, 10, 12, 14. Please note that selecting only 1 element, ie. 6, 8 is also possible.

Comment: @HackNode You could have a look at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/subset-sum-problem-dp-25/ for a general intuition of the dynamic programming solution. I've also added more explanation. Hope that helps.